# How to fix " .gradle\nodejs\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\node.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"

Tags: android, node.js, android-gradle-plugin, graphql

I am working with GraphQl. I have just set up my schema.json and query.graphql. When I build the project to generate java classes I get this error.

> app.gradle\nodejs\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\node.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have tried checking out a few other similarish posts.

- I have tried enabling multiDex.
- I kept working on the memory issue by adding this.. dexOptions {
          incremental = true;
          preDexLibraries = false
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
      }... no luck
- I have cleaned and rebuilt the project
- I tried to find out if any dependencies I might have included
  multiple times. "gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies
  --configuration compile"
- I built a new project to narrow down when this came up and it is only when it is trying to generate the graphql java classes.
- For guesses I removed "implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:0.3.2'" from gradle app dependencies. Didnt change anything.. weird? I found one tutorial not saying I required this part.
- Updated my NPM, no change in error though.

More specifically this is where in the generated file the issue is happening

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugApolloIR'

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?

Comment: Yes I actually wrote my own a answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so ultimately this just meant my query was wrong. To anyway who gets in the same situation as me here is a straight forward fix.

Test your queries on a online graphQL client. If you are using firefox like me I found many clients were incompatible.

> ```
> GraphiQL: This is a type of plugin in your browser which is used to test your queries on the APIs. You can customize your requests by adding URLs and adding on different header types. Link: https://github.com/graphql/graphiql
> Altair GraphQL Client: It is a type of postman for graphQL APIs which is also available as Mozilla Firefox add-on to test the queries. Link: https://github.com/imolorhe/altair
> ```

My Altair Client suggested answers allowing me to build a query from an API with minimal information on access and commands. Once I provided the right query it fixed everything. Also the posted suggestions/attempts in the question

Here is a link to the best explaination on the internet is to setting up Graphql with android. [GraphQL](https://medium.com/mindorks/what-is-graphql-and-using-it-on-android-ab8e493abdd7)

Answer (score 2):

I faced an issue similar to this too. My queries had an issue too but they were working fine in Altair/Insomnia. The error message I got when I ran or rebuilt the project(using the play button or menu options) was `Validation of GraphQL query document failed android apollo client` which wasn't very useful.

I run the build via terminal with the `stacktrace` flag i.e. `./gradlew build --stacktrace` and got much more useful information on what was wrong with my query. It was easy to fix after this. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Issue in the schema file which is inside the graphql folder check the schema file must contain the name of query which you are calling.

For example if you have query

`query FilmsList{
       filmsList{ 
           name
           }
         }`

then filmsList must be available in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and after an hour of trying to solve it I realised I didnt put the ".graphql" extension to my query file.

Be sure that in your graphql folder you put:

- schema.json
- yourQuery.graphql

files.